# Python. Словарь. не понимаю как сделать ввод символов

Tags: python

Не понимаю как отобразить в питоне ввод символов словарем, чтобы ключ каждый раз увеличивался на 1.
Например:
aa vv c fas fd
'aa':1, 'vv':2 .....

как-то нашаманить с этой конструкцией нужно
l={a:b++1 for a in (input().lower().split())}

В дальнейшем мне нужно будет работать со словарем

Comment: Оформите вопрос правильно. Отформатируйте и опишите проблему подробнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если я правильно понял, тебе вводится строка тебе нужно сделать что бы первое
получился словарь `{'первое слово': 1, 'второе слово': 2,...}`

```
result_dict = {
  word: index for index, word in enumerate(input().lower().split(), 1)
}
```

если тебе нужно наоборот, что бы был словарь
`{1: 'первое слово', 2: 'второе слово',...}`
тогда так

```
result_dict = {
  index: word for index, word in enumerate(input().lower().split(), 1)
}
```

но во втором случае непонятно, зачем тебе вообще словарь, можно использовать списки `word_list = input().lower().split()`
у тебя будет `word_list[0] = 'первое слово', word_list[1] = 'второе слово',...`

Comment: выдает ошибку при вызове result_dict[1] и др.

Мне нужна эта часть кода для дальнейшей работы с ним. Далее мне нужно будет сравнивать значения по индексам

Comment: так ты определись, что тебе нужно. что бы ключами словаря были слова которые введены, или ключами должны быть цифры, а значением слово. Добавил второй  вариант в ответ

Comment: я узнал что хотел. спасибо за помощь!
__
пс сорь за некорректный запрос. бессоница - мой худший враг